# Serious Sitecore MVC/Glassmapper issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, glass-mapper

We have a Sitecore site for a client that is throwing an error that seems related to MVC and/or Glassmapper. It happening on the content delivery server when under some load during load testing (not massive). It appears to happen when the site is first compiling. Prior to this event, we get a sitecore shut down ("HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown"), When it restarts the first line of code that's hit in the main view throws an error. If I remove that line, then the line after errors, etc., all the way down the page. It's as if no code can run, like the something become corrupt when it restarted. If I reset IIS the issue goes away. All of our code is complied in the DLLs, except the Razor views, of course.

I know this is all a big vauge, but if anyone has experienced an issue like this or has any ideas where to look, it would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: An unhandled exception occurred.
Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass22.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1e()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<.cctor>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Error while rendering view: '/Views/Chrome.cshtml' (model: 'Castle.Proxies.IPageBaseProxy, DynamicProxyGenAssembly2').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Message: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Source: System.Core
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T value)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.Add(T item)
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.SitecoreFieldStringMapper.GetField(Field field, SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, SitecoreDataMappingContext context)
   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.AbstractSitecoreFieldMapper.MapToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext mappingContext)
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateInterface.InterfacePropertyInterceptor.LoadValues()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateInterface.InterfacePropertyInterceptor.get_Values()
   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateInterface.InterfacePropertyInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IPageBaseProxy.get_TemplateId()
   at ASP._Page_Views_Chrome_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Webroot\Sitecore\Website\Views\Chrome.cshtml:line 11
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

Here's the code that errors:

```
Line 9:      var bodyClass = "";
Line 10: 
Line 11:     if (Model.TemplateId == GlobalId.ArticlePageTemplate.Guid)
Line 12:     {
Line 13:         bodyClass = "pagetype-article";
```

Line 11 is where the error occurs. Don't know if it's the Model that's or our call to the static ID. Keep in mind that this is the very first line of code that calls out to our compiled code (DLL). If I remove it, the next one like it will error. I've tested this for every line of code on the page.

**Got some additional information:**
The server was restarted by an IT guy in this case, so the shutdown was normal and planned. So, I think the load testing is a red herring. Even though we've seen the error happen during load testing, it looks like this situation can happen randomly on first request after the app starts.

Comment: can you show the code for `Chrome.cshtml:line 11` that is triggering the `Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: Added the code from the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue from Glass Mapper and has been fixed:

https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/100

You should update to the newest Glass Mapper version to get rid of this.